# Return the largest possible number from given digits? javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i find the largest number from given digits?

For example:

```
const myFunction = input => {
  return //im not sure how to produce what i need here.
}

myFunction(36);
//Should return 63
```

Comment: Hi! Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Is that you want?

```js
function getMax(number) {
  return parseInt(number.toString().split('').sort(function(a, b) { return b - a }).join(''));
}
console.log(getMax(36), getMax(128945));
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! nice to see the old timers above not willing to help!